# .Net5 using a centralized web applications for login

Tags: jwt, asp.net-identity, microservices, claims-based-identity, .net-5

I'm building a platform on .Net5 that will consist of at least 3 MVC web applications: User, Admin, Product.  Authentication is performed on the User application where we can take a Username/Password to log the user in.  The User Application also has the Forgot Password/Reset Password, etc functionality on it.  Authorization is claims based.  Based on [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/secure-net-microservices-web-applications/) I believe I would fall into Figure 9-2 Authentication by identity microservice, where my other microservices are web applications rather than APIs.

The issue I'm running into is trying to figure out the proper way to implement this.

Do I use JWT or Cookies for this?  The article above does have a link for cookie sharing but wouldn't JWT be appropriate?

If I did use JWT, how do I pass it back to the server if I used something like @Html.ActionLink?  Or is it expected that I would be using a front end framework like React and thus making any calls back to the server manually?

Again, if I'm using JWT, how would I pass it from the User application to the other applications?